# Linker error after upgrading Xcode 7.3 to 8.3.1

Tags: swift, swift3

I am facing linker error after upgrading Xcode from 7.3 to 8.3.1,
below is the error coming at the time of project build:

```
    Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$__TtCC13Test11AppDelegate12loggedinUser", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in UIView+Toast.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Architecture Settings in Build Setting:
[image]

Compile Sources:
[image]
[image]
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: See this link
http://stackoverflow.com/a/26561570/6507951

Comment: @SargisGevorgyan I checked this but it does not solved my problem. It works fine in Xcode 7.3. Problem comes after I upgraded the Xcode.

Comment: Is the target membership of the file is checked ..?

Comment: Yes it is checked.

Comment: @Akash are you using pods ?

Comment: @Jack No I don't use pods in  my project.

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31628890/calling-objective-c-from-swift-class-causing-linker-errors (and the accepted answer there is probably what you need).

Answer (score 0):

Check your `TestAppDelegate` class, especially property `loggedinUser`. There should be some clues.

This may be a problem, that the target you are compiling is using the `UIView+Toast` file, which requires the `TestAppDelegate` to also be compiled.
Check your project settings -> build phases -> compile sources and check if any entries are colored red (missing under the path) or are just not there, and readd them.

Comment: Hello @Alistra, thanks for replying. Every thing fine in project settings -> build phases -> compile sources.

Comment: Do you mean that you have both `UIView+Toast` and `TestAppDelegate` there present?

Comment: No this file is not there in compile source.

Comment: I added TestAppDelegate and still not working. I am stuck here. Pleae help